# Laravel pivot insert table has no column 0

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

i have a problem with sync pivot table
i have 2 models
users and backends

```
class Backend extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','code',
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

}

class User extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','email',
    ];
    public function backends()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Backend::class);
    }
}
```

In backendController i have a store method

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $backend = Backend::create($request->only('name','code'));

        $backend->users()->sync($request->only('users'));
        return response()->json(['response' => $backend ? true : false]);
    }
```

I have this error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table backend_user has no column
>   named 0 (SQL: insert into "backend_user" ("backend_id", "0",
>   "user_id", "1") values (6, 1, users, 3))

How can i resolve this?

thanks